# fish shell: Weird exit command behaviour from terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, exit, fish

I have the **fish shell** installed on my Mac OS X via Homebrew. To configure the Terminal application to use the fish shell instead of the bash shell, I ran `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` once to change my default shell (as recommended by the caveats of the brew installation) and then I added the `fish` command to the end of my `~/.bash_profile` file to have fish open every time a new terminal window opens.

The problem I face is when I exit. Based on what I see on other people's Mac computers that have fish installed the same way I do, typing `exit` will immediately close the window, even though fish is running on top of bash. When I try the same thing, some really funky behaviour happens. First off, the fish shell does not outright exit the terminal window, I now have to exit bash. But, in addition to that, the bash shell is in a really weird state. None of the characters that I type in commands will appear in the command prompt. Also, if I were to press enter, the prompt will not create a new line like in normal circumstances.

There must be some sort of configuration that I have that is off. Any ideas?

---

### Update

I found this link that seems to solve my issue: http://support.apple.com/kb/ta27005

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things you can do:

1. Use `exec fish` at the end of your `.bash_profile`. Instead of running `fish` as a process in `bash`, this instead *replaces* the current instance of `bash` with `fish`, so that when `fish` exits, there are no more programs running in the terminal window and the window closes.
2. You can configure your terminal emulator to run `fish` instead of `bash`, so that `chsh` is unnecessary. Terminal windows only run an instance of your login shell by default.